# Excel Dropdown list dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables, each table on a sheet

```
Table Country (Id, Country Name) Sheet1
Table City (Country Id, City Name) Sheet2
```

And I have 1 table for **persons**

```
Table Persons(ID, Full Name, Country Name, City Name) Sheet3
Data Validation(List): Country Name  (=Country !$B$2:$B$102)
Data Validation(List): City Name     (=City!$B$2:$B$700)
```

**Country Name** is Dropdown list from table **Country**
**City Name** is Dropdown list from table **City**

> How can I when I **choose the country name**, it shows only the names of
> **the city in this country**

> **Note: I use Data Validation**

Comment: I added it, I'm only using it Data Validation @braX

Comment: You question is very minimal. What version of Excel do you use? If you have Office 365 it's quite easy using FILTER. Otherwise we need INDEX/AGGREGATE